# IE7 Bug: CSS background hidden, shows on hover

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, xhtml

I'm having a weird problem in IE7, the CSS background image (bullet) on some `<li>`'s are hidden and visible on others. When I hover over them though, they become visible.

I tried adding `position:relative` on `li` but it didn't help. How do fix this?

Screenshot:

[alt text http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/9261/screenshot20100218at623.png](http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/9261/screenshot20100218at623.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Odd. Can you post an example? Are you 100% sure there are no other definitions interfering?

Comment: I had the same problem! Can not remember how i solved it... I'll be back!

Comment: @Pekka Screenshot included.
@Allan Yeah, I've solved this before but don't remember anymore. :P

Comment: Going to need to see some code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position is Everything have a similar sounding issue listed, called the [Disappearing List-Background Bug](http://positioniseverything.net/explorer/ie-listbug.html).

I noticed they applied `position:relative;` to the `<ul>` not the `<li>` as you've done.  Give that a shot?

Answer (score 1):

One reason may be that you use `list-style-image` or `list-style` property on the li instead of the ul.